# Trying to find a match between strings that ignores the case as well as certain 0s

Tags: python, python-2.7

There are two lists of strings that I am trying to find a match between. They both include strings that have different formatting but they point to the same list of information.

One list include strings that are formatted as  "A02A18"   While the next could have the same string as "a2a18"

Also there are some strings that may look like "A05" that would go with "a5"

I say "certain 0s" in the title because I dont want there to be a string such as "A15A20" and "a15a2" to match if I strip all 0s from from the string (Obviously because 05 is the same as 5 but 20 is not the same as 2)

I am looking for a way that can get them to match each other if found.

It would ideally look like

```
first = "A02A18"
second = "a2a18"

if first == second:
  print "Yes"
```

What I had-

Initially I had a statement that would match strings like "A05" and "a5"
This looked like

```
first = "A05"
second = "a5"

if first[1:].lstrip("0") == second[1:].lstrip("0"):
  print "yeah"
```

this would take both strings and compare them after the first index so in case of the previous example "A05" and a5 would be compared after the first letter to ignore the case. then lstrip "0" would strip the 0 that would be there. I originally did a strip 0 on both sides incase in the future a string had "a05" instead of "a5" (just trying to cover all bases)

While this works for this case, it would not work for a strings such as "A02A18" and "a2a18"

Comment: Ah -- so you need to compare values, considering each alpha string and each integer?

Comment: Please label the source of this problem appropriately.
Someone else posted a *very* similar version of this about an hour ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use regex to remove the zeroes following a letter, and compare the results (uppercasing the source to be able to compare without casing):

```
import re

def compare(s1,s2):
    def convert(s):
        return re.sub("([A-Z])0+",r"\1",s.upper())
    return convert(s1) == convert(s2)


print(compare("A02A18","a2a18"))
print(compare("A20A18","a2a18"))
```

result:

```
True
False
```

note: this also works for `A000B12`: the zeroes are just removed. However, if there's a risk of false positives because inputs can be `A00B1` and `AB1`, then the convert function could create a list of strings + converted integers as an alternative:

```
def convert(s):
    return [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x.upper() for x in re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+|\d+",s)]
```

or a simpler version uppercasing the source from the start (shorter, probably slightly faster because there's only one call to `upper`)

```
def convert(s):
    return [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in re.findall("[A-Z]+|\d+",s.upper())]
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you mean to say that all zeros should be ignored unless the last character is a zero, the following code should be able to perform the task.

```
def main(first, second):

first = first.lower()
second = second.lower()

string = ""

for i in range(0, (len(first)-1)):
    if(first[i] != "0"):
        string = string + first[i]

string = string + first[-1]

if(string == second):
    return True
else:
    return False


answer = main("A02A18", "a2a18")
print(answer)

answer = main("A15A20", "a15a2")
print(answer)
```

This code returns `True` for the first call and `False` for the second. In the future, keep in mind the `string.lower()` and `string.upper()` functions. They are very useful in cases like this.

Comment: that doesn't cover all cases. try `main("A020A18", "a20a18")`. "Assuming that you mean to say that all zeros should be ignored unless the last character is a zero": Your starting hypothesis is wrong